# Windows Phone 8 detect when Image gallery folder has added new image

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, gallery, directory

I have tried searching it but I haven't found anything which could answer my question. I would like to make an app which when the user adds a new image in the gallery (or takes a photo from the camera), then it shows a message.

Do you know if is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You mean some form of a "hook" tak calls your app whenever a new photo is save to the device? Nothing like this is possible.